# run FQL query after Facebook api initialization

Tags: facebook-fql

I am trying to run some facebook query just after initializing the api using the following code :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({...});

    makeCall(); // this won't work
   setTimeout(makeCall, 1000); // this will work 
};

var makeCall = function() {
    console.log("exec some query ")
    var query = FB.Data.query("SELECT ...");
    query.wait(function(friends) {
        console.log("query result ...");
    });
}
```

Somehow the query only get executed when I set a time out. Is there some better way of doing that rather than setting some timeout

Answer (score 0):

try to move makeCall definition inside the window.fbAsyncInit = function() scope
for example immediately after FB.init call.

hope this helps